# running iis7.5 on 32-bit windows 2008 (not r2)

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

Does anyone know if it's possible to run IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008.  From what I understand Windows Server 2008 R2 is an exclusively 64-bit OS.  Can we upgrade IIS7 to IIS7.5 on Windows 2008 (not R2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot.  IIS has always been tied to an OS release and is only available on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

Keep in mind that a 64-bit OS runs most 32-bit things just fine in [WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) (Including IIS application pools), are you prohibited from running something on that server this way?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in particular that you need? Some of the features of 2008 R2 are available for download at http://www.iis.net/download including the Admin Pack, WebDAV, FTP 7.5 and more.